# Java get() time method

Tags: java, time

Im working on the following question:

> A time by the 24-hour clock is a 4-digit number where the leftmost two
>   digits denote the hour (0 to 23, incl.) and the rightmost two digits
>   denote the minutes (0 to 59, incl.). For example, 2130 expresses
>   half-past nine in the evening. Write a class Time to encapsulate a
>   time. It should have the following instance methods:
>
> get to read a time from the keyboard (supplied as a four-digit number
>   e.g. 2130). You may assume the number represents a valid time.

My code so far is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Time {

private double hour, min;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Time() {
    hour = 00;
    min = 00;
}

Time(double h, double m) {
    hour = h;
    min = m;
}

void get() {
    System.out.println("Please enter a time in 24 hour format: ");
    double x = scanner.nextDouble();
    hour = x / 100;
    min = x % 100;
    System.out.println("The time is " + hour + ":" + min);
}

public String toString() {
    return "Time: " + hour + min;
}
}
```

The problem I have is how to split the 4 digit input into hour and minute, all advice, tips appreciated.

Comment: Studying for an upcoming (repeat) exam Johnathan and doing sample excercises, this question is a lot longer than what I have above placed above. Its also Summer, ie no university and no homework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for an *integer* `x` with 4 digits:

```
x / 100 - gives the 2 left digits
x % 100 - gives the 2 right digits
```

**EDIT:** Assuming here the heading zeros are silently omitted, since 0000 is translated to 0 as an integer, and will yield hour=0 (translated to 00), min=0 (translated to 00) - as it supposed to.

Comment: Thanks Amit, when implementing your answer I get the following output: Please enter a time in 24 hour format: 
1245
The time is 12.45:45.0
Iv never seen the technique above so can you advise why this occurs?

Comment: @Dave: make sure you are using `int` types, and not `double`s. You can read an int using [`scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

Answer (score 6):

Read in the input as a `String` then use `substring()` method to get the individual hours and minutes:

```
String s=scanner.nextLine();

String hours=s.substring(0,2);//hour
String minutes=s.substring(2,4);//min

System.out.println("The time is " + hours + ":" + minutes);
```